# Skip header AND columns if all columns are empty i CSV

Tags: python, csv

Im trying to read som CSV files and clean it up a bit if columns under header has no values.

```
Name,ID,State
Tom,,California
Jim,,Texas
```

Then the new CSV should only have the columns Name,State.

```
def clean_csv(csvfile):
    with open('./user.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF8') as infile, open('./user_clean.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        headers = next(reader, None)
        for row in reader:
            if any(row):
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Why not read it into a dateframe, use its builtin functions to clean empty values columns, and write it back to a CSV?

Comment: The problem is that some columns has multiple headers with exact same name and then the df messes it up. I want to do just a quick clean first.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read the whole file to know which ,columns are to be kept. So you only have 2 options:

- read everything in memory, identify the empty columns and then write back the relevant ones. Simple but may exhaust memory if the file is huge
- use 2 pass. Identify at first pass which columns are to be kept and do the real copy on second pass. Saves memory but reads the file twice

I will just show the second one, for the first one, just add each row to a list during the first pass and use that list on second pass:

```
with open('input.csv') as fd, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd)
    cols = set()
    _ = next(rd)  # skip header line
    for row in rd:
        for i, val in enumerate(row):
            if val != '':
                cols.add(i)
    _ = fd.seek(io.SEEK_SET)
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    for row in rd:
        _ = wr.writerow(val for i, val in enumerate(row) if i in cols)
```

With your example data, it gives as expected:

```
Name,State
Tom,California
Jim,Texas
```

Comment: OMG! Worked perfectly, HUUUUGE thanks to you Serge! I would never have solved that my self!

Comment: I know Im asking to much now but, can I combine this with a function that removes any digit from the headers that the dict has created? I have "Comments1","Comments2" and so on. Just like:

header = ''.join([i for i in header if not i.isdigit()])